# Does Muriel Barbery's title "The Elegance of The Hedgehog" reflect knowledge of Archilochus' aphorism?

Tags: french-language, title, allusions, muriel-barbery, the-elegance-of-the-hedgehog

Does Muriel Barbery's title *The Elegance of The Hedgehog* reflect knowledge of Archilochus' aphorism? Is there information or proof that Barbery had Archilocus' aphorism in mind?

Comment: How could she not know?